# Display Outlook Add-ins next to new items of Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I have a created an outlook Add-Ins and its working as expected. The newly installed add-in is displayed at the Home tab of outlook. It is displayed as a new group.

I need my add-in to get displayed next to new item option present in outlook.

For better understanding please see the image. I need my add in exactlt at the yellow coloured position.

Code snippet

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.tabCustomHome = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
        this.group1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
        this.menuButton1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonMenu();
        this.btnLogin = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.btnLogout = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.tabCustomHome.SuspendLayout();
        this.group1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabCustomHome
        // 
        this.tabCustomHome.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
        this.tabCustomHome.ControlId.OfficeId = "TabMail";
        this.tabCustomHome.Groups.Add(this.group1);
        this.tabCustomHome.Label = "TabMail";
        this.tabCustomHome.Name = "tabCustomHome";
        // 
        // group1
        // 
        this.group1.Items.Add(this.menuButton1);
        this.group1.Label = "Sample";
        this.group1.Name = "group1";
        // 
        // menuButton1
        // 
        this.menuButton1.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.menuButton1.Dynamic = true;
        this.menuButton1.Image = global::SHOutlookLogin.Properties.Resources.Sales;
        this.menuButton1.Label = " ";
        this.menuButton1.Name = "menuButton1";
        this.menuButton1.ShowImage = true;
        // 
        // btnLogin
        // 
        this.btnLogin.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.btnLogin.Label = "Login";
        this.btnLogin.Name = "btnLogin";
        this.btnLogin.ShowImage = true;
        this.btnLogin.Click += BtnLogin_Click;
        // 
        // btnLogout
        // 
        this.btnLogout.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.btnLogout.Label = "Logout";
        this.btnLogout.Name = "btnLogout";
        this.btnLogout.ShowImage = true;
        this.btnLogout.Click += BtnLogout_Click;
        // 
        // OutlookLoginRibbon
        // 
        this.Name = "OutlookLoginRibbon";
        this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer";
        this.Tabs.Add(this.tabCustomHome);
        this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.OutlookLoginRibbon_Load);
        this.tabCustomHome.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabCustomHome.PerformLayout();
        this.group1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.group1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }



    #endregion

    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab tabCustomHome;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup group1;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton btnLogin;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton btnLogout;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonMenu menuButton1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following markup:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="ribbonLoaded_Callback">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab getVisible="getVisible_Callback" idMso="TabMail">
        <group getLabel="getLabel_Callback" getScreentip="getScreenTip_Callback" getVisible="getVisible_Callback" id="RibbonGroup_3b56363af4b447adb1126bb6791405c7" insertAfterMso="GroupMailNew">
           <button getDescription="getDescription_Callback" getEnabled="getEnabled_Callback" getKeytip="getKeytip_Callback" getLabel="getLabel_Callback" getScreentip="getScreenTip_Callback" getShowImage="getShowImage_Callback" getShowLabel="getShowLabel_Callback" getSize="getSize_Callback" getVisible="getVisible_Callback" id="RibbonButton_7f2ec50f5d65467fbcf3cadef7e8ab15" onAction="onActionCommon_Callback" />
        </group>
     </tab>
   </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

As a result, you should get the following picture in Outlook:

[image: Outlook 2013 with a custom ribbon controls on a built-in tab]

You may find the [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2017) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I need the same from C# code. can you help me?

Comment: You just need to define the `GetCustomUI` callback in the code. The rest of the callbacks is up to you.

Comment: I have added a walkthrough which provides the required steps for creating a ribbon tab with a C# sample code.

Comment: I have added my current code. If am not wrong I need to add some ID displaying it next to new items. It will be great if u help me on what changes I should do in my code. Since am new to outlook add-in am not much familiar to it.

Comment: You may find the required `idMso` values in the markup provided above.

Comment: I have already set office ID as TabMail.. there is no option for idMso in tab.
 this.tabCustomHome.ControlId.OfficeId = "TabMail";

Comment: The group has the following attribute - ` insertAfterMso="GroupMailNew" `

Comment: RibbonGroup has no attribute insertAfterMso, am trying to code in c#. But the same can be done by XML.